# Makefile, macro modifiers

Tags: macros, path, makefile, substitution, modifiers

I relatively new to writing make files and could use some pointers. What I'm trying to achieve is probably fairly basic but after searching the web I fail to understand how.

I would like to compile a set of object files from a src directory into a build directory and my naive idea were to define the set of source files as a macro, use macro modifiers to create a macro for the object files (so that these are properly compared to the source files when recompiling. My current scheme fro creating the object files macro looks as:

```
SRCDIR = /some/dir/
BUILDDIR = /some/dir/
CSRC = \
        $(SRCDIR)f1.c \
        $(SRCDIR)f2.c \

OSRC = $(CSRC,.c=.o,F,<$(BUILDDIR))

all:
    @echo $(OSRC)
```

where the all rule is simply put in to check if the object files macro is set properly. Unfortunately it is not, instead it is empty. Replacing

```
OSRC = $(CSRC,.c=.o,F,<$(BUILDDIR))
```

by

```
OSRC = $(CSRC:.c=.o)
```

does give me a macro of object files but not with the proper directories. Thus insight on how to modify my file to get what I want would be appreciated. (I'm using GNU Make 3.82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got `$(CSRC,.c=.o,F,<$(BUILDDIR))`; there's nothing even remotely like that syntax in GNU make.

The statement `$(CSRC:.c=.o)` replaces all the `.c` suffixes with `.o`, but that doesn't help you because you also want to replace the directory.

You should use the `$(patsubst ...)` function:

```
OSRC = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)%.c,$(BUILDDIR)%.o,$(CSRC))
```

Comment: Yup your are quit right, after a second look at the homepage where I got the syntax i realize that this is not GNU make syntax but Opus Make, sorry for my confusion and thanks for the correct syntax using GNU.